# Two different URLs, one Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I have the same WordPress site run on two different URLs?

For example, [www.brand1.com](http://www.brand1.com) and [www.brand2.com](http://www.brand2.com). They have the SAME content, just some different graphics or ads (which could be handled in javascipt?).

I don't think multisite is what I need because that runs two different sites on the same instance of WordPress. What I need is to run the same site twice (with shared SQL and php) but give each a slightly different "look" or "branding".

I'm not sure if URL rewriting will work. The examples I've seen just rewrite the path (after the server part of the url).

TIA

Comment: Does this answers your question? [Is it possible for many domain names to share one IP address?](https://superuser.com/questions/577070/is-it-possible-for-many-domain-names-to-share-one-ip-address)

Comment: Not a programming question, as such. You should ask on [wordpress.se]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of plugins available that allow you to map multiple domains to a single WordPress site. One popular option is the Multiple Domain Mapping plugin.

To use this plugin, you would first need to install and activate it on your WordPress site. Then, you would need to add the additional domains that you want to use to the plugin's settings. Once you have added the domains you will need to update your DNS records to point the domains to your WordPress site.

Once you have updated your DNS records, the additional domains will be mapped to your WordPress site and you will be able to access the site using any of the domains.

I have found this info from web.

Comment: Hmmm. Looks kind of promising, but the description specifically says it is not intended to do what I need: a complete website domain map (i.e., every page on one domain is mapped to the other domain). Thanks for the reply, it gives me more to search on.